# htaccess get redirect URI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have rewrite rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/d/categories$ /categories.php [L]
```

which gives `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` = **/d/categories**

But now i have some requirement to add one more level of **redirect**

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /d/categories [L]
```

which gives  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` = **(empty)**

Is there any `htaccess` flag with which we can get or is it plain not possible which is what i am thinking right now?

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` = **/d/categories**

I have already tried `L`, `P` and `PT` none is working. I can't add redirect rule to redirect from `/` to `/d/categories` which will than work from **Rule 1**

Comment: Can you just assume that if REQUEST_URI is empty then it's /d/categories?

Comment: @jcubic I can do something like that but i want to know if we can achieve what i am facing issue with. actually `PT` flag does something like that mentioned here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: I'm confused at your requirement. What does this mean **But now i have some requirement to add one more level of redirect**? Can you get clearer of what you want to do and are you putting this in .htaccess or apache config?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, **you need 2 rules**. Redirect the root to your your /d/categories then let that rule be processed by your PHP file. The server can not send a URI request from which it has not been requested. How is it supposed to know if the user goes to root to redirect to /d/categories without telling it? It will have to be redirected first or you need to assume that if it's `REQUEST_URI` is blank they requested the your main domain.

Try these rules

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /d/categories [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?d/categories$ /categories.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /d/categories [L, R=301]
```

Comment: No, I don't want to redirect. Sorry, i forgot to mention that :)

Answer (score 0):

The `[L]` stands for "last".

So you need to get rid of it in the first statement:

```
RewriteRule ^/d/categories$ /categories.php
RewriteRule ^/$ /d/categories [L]
```